# Listening on many ports for mTLS ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, port

How can I setup listening multiple ports? On first port I want to have default app with https, on another I want to use HTTPS and require SSL based authentication with client certificates. How to do it? This is my current `Startup.cs` code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
{
    kestrelOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpOptions =>
    {
        httpOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
    });
});

var services = builder.Services;

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
        cfg.LoginPath = "/account/login";
        cfg.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    })
    .AddCertificate(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        cfg.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
    });

services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My goal is to use Certificate authentication on some endpoints (and don't display certificate request e.g. for web explorer users) and not use delayed certificates.

Comment: HTTPS uses TLS for encryption.  The TLS is done before the HTTP Request is sent.  So any HTTPS cannot be done with the request.  Authentication is credentials and not encryption which is done after the http connection completes.  You are confusing the certificate that is used with TLS and the certificate that is used for login credentials.

Comment: @jdweng: I think the OP meant TLS based authentication with client certificates, which unfortunately was only visible from the mTLS instead of TLS in the title. I've changed the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : The OP is using CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme which is not TLS.  Look at OPs sample code before making comments.

Comment: I use Cookie authentication as default scheme, but sometimes I have to use Certificate scheme that is added by `AddCertificate` in above code. I changed a bit my question and defined my goal.

Comment: I'm afraid your requirement is impossible to be realized by code. And you may divide your project into 2 projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with kestrelOptions.ListenLocalhost:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
{
    kestrelOptions.ListenLocalhost(8080, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseHttps(httpOptions =>
        {
            httpOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
        });
    });
    kestrelOptions.ListenLocalhost(8081, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseHttps(httpOptions =>
        {
            httpOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate;
        });
    });
});
```

Now one port is for mTLS (8080) and another don't require certificate! Works really nice.